# Google Analytics not tracking E-Commerce transaction

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have an issue with the Magento Google Analytics module on one site I have developed.

I have checked the code and compared to another site that I know works.

`$this->getOrderIds()` in `getOrdersTrackingData()` of `ga.php` appears to always be blank regardless of what I do.

I have manually added a real order id and this gets the data from the database and outputs it to the block correctly.

I have determined that the `$orderIds` variable has the correct data in

```
SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver.php
```

I am at a loss as to why this would not be work anyone one got any ideas?

Comment: Do you use third party checkout module?

Comment: Sohel, thanks for replying. No, we are using the standard one page checkout within Magento.  The only plugin we are using is the SagePaySuite from Ebizmarts.

Comment: Just a quick "dummy-check", do you have GA enabled in `Admin->Stores->Configuration->Sales->Google API->Google Analytics`?  Also, do you have the correct Account Number entered?

Comment: Analytics is collecting data fine for page views and on the correct account.  The only thing that is missing is the order data due to the OrderIds array being empty.  If I set the array manually, the data is returned for the order specified.  Strange one!

Comment: @Dan Did you get to the bottom of this? ordersTrackingData  = []  is always empty What your finding can you share please? thanks.

Comment: Anyone Looking for the fix found a bug fix here https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/24a5abd95a177d9e21f5c2791931e6d104be42aa

Answer (score 1):

@Dan

There is an Bug on This File

> /vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/view/frontend/web/js/google-analytics.js

It can't check the length of an object therefore you can check `currency property` like so:

```
if (config.ordersTrackingData.hasOwnProperty('currency'))
```

bug fix ref:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/24a5abd95a177d9e21f5c2791931e6d104be42aa

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this type of issue occurs because of "**Cookie Restriction Mode**". So, please **select "No" if you selected "Yes"** for it. Try this if it may help you.
Please refer the following screenshot....

[image]

Comment: Please add a reason on down voting. Just voting down is not very helpful.